# terminal: % node example.js -bash: fg: no such job

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, terminal

In Terminal, when I try to run `% node example.js` why do I get `-bash: fg: %: no such job`?

I've installed Node.js. I've saved example.js with the example code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

This is following the webserver example on the landing page of http://nodejs.org/.

Comment: `%` is used to define a job, it expects a job identifier(number,string,etc) after it. Also i think on that website they are using `%` as the prompt. Try just `node example.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `node example.js` is successful without the `%`.

`node example.js` results in:
`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/`

> % is used to define a job, it expects a job identifier(number,string,etc) after it.
>   Also i think on that website they are using % as the prompt.
>   Try just node example.js
>   –  Jidder

Credit: [Jidder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3442743/jidder)

Answer (score 0):

% is often used as the prompt, I had a similar situation when running a mongo shell command from mongolab.

Run the command after the %.